# Looking for anime a sword, an axe and a bow activating robots

Tags: madou-king-granzort

I am looking for an old anime in which there are three people (two male and one female if I remember).
One of them has red robot and activates him with his sword, other one is green and activates it with a bow, and the third one is girl in blue and I think she has an axe. And they fight other robots.
Anyone remembers which anime it was?

Comment: why you use the live-action tag?

Comment: Sorry, mistake. Will remove it now.

Comment: This combo is somewhat like [Golden Axe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Axe).

Comment: No, it is not that. The look of the characters is similar like Dragon Ball if I remember well.

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer on some forum. I was looking for **[Madou King Granzort](http://myanimelist.net/anime/2818/Madou_King_Granzort)**.

[image: Madou King Granzort cover]

> In the future, the moon is a habitable place with atmosphere and gravity and also a famous tourist attraction. There are also stories about a "long ears" creature like rabbits on the moon who can use magic. Haruka Daichi heads off to the moon during a summer holiday alone because he likes to see the long ears creature by himself.
>
> However, he get himself dragged into an acient conflict between two acient moon racess: the "long ears" race and Jado race. Jado race wanted to conquer the universe and resurrect ancient evil powers to seize control of the Earth. Now the "long ears" race and Daichi must seek three warriors who could use magic to release Mado King to fight Jado race and to release "long ears" race`s kingdom, Rabiluna, from Jado race.

The descriptions in the question contain some minor error. According to Wikipedia:

> Soon, Daichi, V-Mei and Guri Guri meet two other **boys** – Gus and Rabi. Gus receives a magic bow that summons Winzart – the Madou King of Wind, while Rabi receives a magic **top** that summons Aquabeat – the Madou King of Water.